# SQL Server Xquery retrieve generated id for child parent relationship

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, sql-server-openxml

Is it possible to use Xpath in a query to get child parent relation ship using XQuery. 
If I use `EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML,  '<xmlns:ns="http://some_namespace"/>'` and after that use the metadata properties
I will receive a correct parent - child id relationship i.e

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENXML(@hDoc,'/ns:root/ns:component/ns:indicator')
WITH(
componentID INT '@mp:parentid',
indicatorID INT '@mp:id',
componentIndicatorType VARCHAR(5) '@sometype') componentIndicators
```

This works but if I were to use XQuery is this without any sp_xml_preparedocument  and instead directly access a table storing the XML in a xml column with an index like

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'http://some_namespace' AS ns   )
     select
   **** --> Here I would like to retrieve a parent -- child relation id 
   f.i.value(N'@sometype', N'nvarchar(100)') AS sometype
from dbo.xmldatatest AS  T
  cross apply T.xmldata.nodes('ns:root/ns:component/ns:indicator') as f(i)
```

So is it possible to get such a node relationship when you don't have that explicitly in the xml as attributes using xquery?

Secondly is there a preferred way (OPENXML/XQuery) related to performance and scalability when you have GB+ size xml documents ?

Comment: do you have any sample input?

Comment: something like this <root>
 <order otype="1">
  <orderdetail dtype="1"/>
 </order>
 <order otype="B">
  <orderdetail dtype="X"/>
 </order>
</root>